# display current month as a calendar using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to write a t-sql to display current month in calendar format?

the output should be like

```
sun  mon  tues  wed  thur  fri  sat
           1      2     3     4    5
6    7     8      9     10    11   12
13   14    15     ................
```

should give the current month calendar

This is what I have so far

```
declare @start int
declare @day int
declare @space varchar(100)
declare @nodays int
select @start=1
select @space=''
select @nodays=datediff(dd,getdate(),dateadd(mm,1,getdate()))
select @day=case datename(dw,cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(10)) + '-' +cast(month(getdate()) as varchar(10)) + '-' +cast(day(getdate()) as varchar(10))) when 'Sunday' then 1 when 'Monday' then 2 when 'tuesday' then 3 when 'wednesday' then 4 when 'thursday' then 5 when 'friday' then 6 when 'saturday' then 7 end
while(@start<=@nodays)
    if(@day=1)
        if(len(@space)=0)
            select @space=cast(@start as varchar(10))
        else
            select @space=@space+' '+
            case when len(cast(@start as varchar(10)))=1 
            then ' ' 
            else '' 
            end +
            cast(@start as varchar(10))
    else
        if(len(@space)=0)
            select @space=@space+ 
            replicate(char(10),@start) +
            case when len(cast(@start as varchar(10)))=1 
            then ' ' 
            else '' 
            end +
            cast(@start as varchar(10))
        else
            select @space=@space+char(10) + case when len(cast(@start as varchar(10)))=1 then ' ' else '' end +cast(@start as varchar(10))
    select @start=@start+1
print @space+char(10)
```

Comment: please format your code so that it is actually legible.

Comment: SELECT supports multiple variables to be set in a single statement...

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic723085-149-1.aspx . Maybe it is what you are looking for.

Comment: You are missing a `begin`...`end` pair. As is, this will loop forever.

Comment: Displaying a month calendar is really not what T-SQL is designed for.... maybe you need to do this in your favorite front-end programming language instead? (C#, Java, VB - whatever)

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[DUPLICATE\] sql query to display current month in calendar format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152424/duplicate-sql-query-to-display-current-month-in-calendar-format)

Comment: @agnes, I have tried to consolidate the information from your three questions into this one. If you have further information to add, you can `edit`this question to do just that, there is no need to create a **new** question.

Comment: @agnes Asking the same question over and over is not acceptable here.  Also, the pattern of questions you are asking suggests you are using us to debug each little step, and can be considered abusive of the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the getdate() to a local declared variable if you like.

```
;with monthDates
as
(
    select  DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()),0) as d
            ,DATEPART(week, DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()),0)) as w
    union all
    select  DATEADD(day, 1, d)
            ,DATEPART(week, DATEADD(day, 1, d))
    from monthDates
    where d < DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())+1,-1)
)

select  max(case when datepart(dw, d) = 1 then datepart(d,d) else null end) as [Sun]
        ,max(case when datepart(dw, d) = 2 then datepart(d,d) else null end) as [Mon]
        ,max(case when datepart(dw, d) = 3 then datepart(d,d) else null end) as [Tue]
        ,max(case when datepart(dw, d) = 4 then datepart(d,d) else null end) as [Wed]
        ,max(case when datepart(dw, d) = 5 then datepart(d,d) else null end) as [Thu]
        ,max(case when datepart(dw, d) = 6 then datepart(d,d) else null end) as [Fri]
        ,max(case when datepart(dw, d) = 7 then datepart(d,d) else null end) as [Sat]
from monthDates
group by w
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you actually are trying to do here. Printing the calender month with T-SQL is probably not what you want to do.

Here is a query that gives you all dates within the current month as a result set. If you just want the day number of the month (like you did) you can use `datepart(d, [Date])` to get that.

```
;with cteLim as
(
  select
    dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, getdate()), 0) as FirstDay,
    dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, getdate())+1, 0)-1 as LastDay
),
cteDays as
(
  select FirstDay as [Date]
  from cteLim
  union all
  select cteDays.[Date] + 1 as [Date]
  from cteDays
    inner join cteLim
      on cteDays.[Date] < cteLim.LastDay
)    
select [Date]
from cteDays
```

Same function but split result to as "calender"

```
;with cteLim as
(
  select
    dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, getdate()), 0) as FirstDay,
    dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, getdate())+1, 0)-1 as LastDay
),
cteDays as
(
  select FirstDay as [Date]
  from cteLim
  union all
  select cteDays.[Date] + 1 as [Date]
  from cteDays
    inner join cteLim
      on cteDays.[Date] < cteLim.LastDay
)    
select
  datepart(iso_week, [Date]) as [Week],
  (select datepart(d, D2.[Date])
   from cteDays as D2
   where
    datepart(iso_week, D2.[Date]) = datepart(iso_week, D1.[Date]) and
    datepart(dw, D2.[Date]) = 2) as Mon,
  (select datepart(d, D2.[Date])
   from cteDays as D2
   where
    datepart(iso_week, D2.[Date]) = datepart(iso_week, D1.[Date]) and
    datepart(dw, D2.[Date]) = 3) as Tue,
  (select datepart(d, D2.[Date])
   from cteDays as D2
   where
    datepart(iso_week, D2.[Date]) = datepart(iso_week, D1.[Date]) and
    datepart(dw, D2.[Date]) = 4) as Wed,
  (select datepart(d, D2.[Date])
   from cteDays as D2
   where
    datepart(iso_week, D2.[Date]) = datepart(iso_week, D1.[Date]) and
    datepart(dw, D2.[Date]) = 5) as Thu,
  (select datepart(d, D2.[Date])
   from cteDays as D2
   where
    datepart(iso_week, D2.[Date]) = datepart(iso_week, D1.[Date]) and
    datepart(dw, D2.[Date]) = 6) as Fri,
  (select datepart(d, D2.[Date])
   from cteDays as D2
   where
    datepart(iso_week, D2.[Date]) = datepart(iso_week, D1.[Date]) and
    datepart(dw, D2.[Date]) = 7) as Sat,
  (select datepart(d, D2.[Date])
   from cteDays as D2
   where
    datepart(iso_week, D2.[Date]) = datepart(iso_week, D1.[Date]) and
    datepart(dw, D2.[Date]) = 1) as Sun
from cteDays as D1
group by datepart(iso_week, [Date])
```

Result

```
Week        Mon         Tue         Wed         Thu         Fri         Sat         Sun
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
9           NULL        1           2           3           4           5           6
10          7           8           9           10          11          12          13
11          14          15          16          17          18          19          20
12          21          22          23          24          25          26          27
13          28          29          30          31          NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Comment: I want it to be displayed in the form of calender

Comment: @sherin Add a picture to your question that shows the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

Forget your 'procedural code to fabricate a calendar on the fly' approach: SQL is a declarative language so instead think in terms of set-based solutions.

Create a permanent `Calendar` table containing all past and future dates you are likely to ever need (should only amount to mere tens of thousands of rows) then query this table when required using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

See [Why should I consider using an auxiliary calendar table?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html)

Answer (score 1):

`select DATEPART(MONTH,getdate())` -- gets month number

`select Datename(month,getdate())` -- gets month name

Answer (score 0):

here a link for : [Creating a Calendar in a single SQL statement](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2029)

```
SELECT LPAD(MONTH, 20 - (20 - LENGTH(MONTH)) / 2) MONTH, "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed",     "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
  FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmMonthfm YYYY') MONTH,
               TO_CHAR(dt + 1, 'iw') week,
               MAX(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dt, 'd'), '1', LPAD(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Sun",
               MAX(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dt, 'd'), '2', LPAD(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Mon",
               MAX(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dt, 'd'), '3', LPAD(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Tue",
               MAX(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dt, 'd'), '4', LPAD(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Wed",
               MAX(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dt, 'd'), '5', LPAD(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Thu",
               MAX(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dt, 'd'), '6', LPAD(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Fri",
               MAX(DECODE(TO_CHAR(dt, 'd'), '7', LPAD(TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmdd'), 2))) "Sat"
          FROM (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'y') - 1 + ROWNUM dt
                  FROM all_objects
                  WHERE ROWNUM <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'y'), 12) -
                       TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'y'))
         GROUP BY TO_CHAR(dt, 'fmMonthfm YYYY'), TO_CHAR(dt + 1, 'iw'))
 ORDER BY TO_DATE(MONTH, 'Month YYYY'), TO_NUMBER(week);
```

You could add some clauses to specify the month

Comment: can we write this in microsoft sql server?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Year int, @Month int, @LastDay int;
SET @Year = 2011;
SET @Month = 2;
SET @LastDay = DAY(DATEADD(m, 1, CAST(@Year AS varchar) + '-' +
                                 CAST(@Month AS varchar) + '-01') - 1);

WITH dates AS (
  SELECT *, DOW = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date), WN = DATEPART(WEEK, Date)
  FROM (
    SELECT
      Date = CAST(CAST(@Year AS varchar) + '-' +
                  CAST(@Month AS varchar) + '-' +
                  CAST(number AS varchar) AS datetime)
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P'
      AND number BETWEEN 1 AND @LastDay
  ) s
)
SELECT
  Sun = MAX(CASE days.DOW WHEN 1 THEN dates.Date END),
  Mon = MAX(CASE days.DOW WHEN 2 THEN dates.Date END),
  Tue = MAX(CASE days.DOW WHEN 3 THEN dates.Date END),
  Wed = MAX(CASE days.DOW WHEN 4 THEN dates.Date END),
  Thu = MAX(CASE days.DOW WHEN 5 THEN dates.Date END),
  Fri = MAX(CASE days.DOW WHEN 6 THEN dates.Date END),
  Sat = MAX(CASE days.DOW WHEN 7 THEN dates.Date END)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DOW FROM dates) days
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT WN FROM dates) weeks
  LEFT JOIN dates ON weeks.WN = dates.WN AND days.DOW = dates.DOW
GROUP BY weeks.WN
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing but a funny SQL exercise, and this is a posible multilanguage approach:

```
set nocount on
declare @q nvarchar(900), @d date = getDate(), @i int = 0
set @q  = 'declare @d date='''
        + convert(char(8), dateAdd(d, 1 - day(@d), @d), 112)
        + ''',@i int,@s char(3)='''';select @i=month(@d),'
        + '@d=dateAdd(d,1-datePart(dw,@d),@d);select '
while @i < 7
    select @q += case @i when 0 then '' else ',' end
        + 'case month(dateAdd(d,' + cast(@i as char(1))
        + '+n,@d))when @i then right(@s+dateName(d,dateAdd(d,'
        + cast(@i as char(1)) + '+n,@d)),3)else @s end['
        + left(dateName(dw, @i + @@DATEFIRST - 1), 3) + ']'
        , @i += 1
set @q += 'from(values(0),(7),(14),(21),(28),(35))v(n)'
print dateName(m, @d) + ' ' + dateName(yy, @d)
exec (@q)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0d0WJMrI)